# Short text-pieces analysis with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have a list/database with short lines of text. Maybe one million such lines. Every line 10-60 characters. I need to categorize them, in the simplest case there would be just two categories, e.g.: "interesting" and "not interesting/spam".

Example

| short text | category |
| --- | --- |
| call me asap | interesting |
| ahahaha | spam |
| ... | ... |
| my address is Newstreet 1001 | interesting |
| this is just a dummy | spam |
| it is a good weather today | spam |
| ... | ... |

I need to provide a proof of concept, if this list can be successfully processed with machine learning tools. E.g. in python.

1. Do I understand it correct that this kind of problems can be solved by classification ML algorithms? Or there are other, better, more promising approaches?
2. Given, I would like to try the proof of concepts in python, is the *sklearn* library the tool of choice?
3. Can somebody provide a link to a "ML classification hello world" example for machine learning newbies?
   I have found these:

   - https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-with-python-classification-complete-tutorial-d2c99dc524ec
   - https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-classify-data-in-python/

   but... well, maybe there are even shorter and better and even more understandable newbie-examples? If possible, in python.

I know, there were similar questions here in the past like

- [Sophisticated models for classifying short pieces of texts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19222/sophisticated-models-for-classifying-short-pieces-of-texts)
- [Machine Learning for Text Classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125072/machine-learning-for-text-classification)

but they are rather old and I would like to know the state of the art.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.